# How do I make radio buttons sit inside label and center text next to them?

Tags: html, css, alignment

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnpenner/uyHYW/1/)

```css
* {
    font-family:sans-serif;
}
#quote_form table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
#quote_form td, #quote_form th {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#quote_form fieldset>label {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 7px;
}

#quote_form input {
    height: 16px;
    padding: 2px;
}
#quote_form select {
    height: 22px;
    padding: 2px;
}

#quote_form td>label {
    font-size: .9em;
}
#quote_form td {
    padding-right: 3px;
}
#quote_form td>input {
    width: 200px;
}
#quote_form .required {
    color: red;
}
#quote_form input {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
#quote_form fieldset>input {
    width: 500px;
}
#quote_form fieldset>select {
    width:  504px;
}
#quote_form fieldset {
    border: 1px solid silver;
    padding: 10px;
}
#quote_form legend {
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding: 2px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#quote_form .calendar {
    width: 80px;
}
#quote_form .datetime td {
    padding: 0;
}
#quote_form .datetime .date {
    padding-right: 4px;
}
#quote_form .datetime .hour {
    font-weight:bold;
}
#quote_form .datetime .minute {
    padding-right: 4px;
}
#quote_form .datetime .ampm input {
    margin: 0 2px 0 0;
}
#quote_form .datetime .ampm label {
    text-align: baseline;
    margin-right: 2px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<form id="quote_form">
    <table class="datetime">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="date"><input type="text" class="calendar"></td>
                <td class="hour"><select></select>:</td>
                <td class="minute"><select></select></td>
                <td class="ampm">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="pickup_ampm">AM</label>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="pickup_ampm">PM</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Date</label></td>
                <td><label>HH</label></td>
                <td><label>MM</label></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

The radio buttons are poking out of the gray label. I want them to sit a little bit lower so that they're centered beside the label text. I tried negative margins -- didn't work.

Comment: Shouldn't `input` be outside `label`? Do you really have to put them inside?

Comment: @SidharthMudgal: I don't have to, but I like to.

Answer (score 4):

This should do what you want, if I understand correctly.

```
.ampm label{
    display:block;
    float: left;
    padding:2px 4px;
}
```

Comment: I should also mention that the label element should not wrap around the input. You should use something more like <div class="wrapper"><radio><label>am</label></div>. and apply the above style to the div rather than the label.

Comment: Why? I specifically like to wrap the input element as well as it makes the whole area clickable, including any spaces between, and there's no need for a "for"/"id" pair, and it's never caused any issues in any browser I've tested.

Comment: This CSS makes the label background cover the whole radio, but there's still the issue of vertically centering..although I might be able to do this with line-height now that it's a block..

Comment: @Mark The HTML and XHTML specifications allow both implicit and explicit labels. However, some assistive technologies do not correctly handle implicit labels (for example, <label>First name <input type="text" name="firstname"></label>). Source: [link]http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20081211/H44.html

Comment: So just for screen readers then? I'll take that into consideration, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using windows8 here works great.

Any way try this method.

```
label > input[type="radio"]
{
    position: relative; // Don't forgot this line
    top: -5px; // Change this value to set exact place.
}
```

anther automatic way is

```
label > input[type="radio"]
{
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```